# iOS: why is my recurrence rule not added?

Tags: ios, calendar

I am creating reminders with alarms. They work fine. Now i want to add recurrence rules, with this code:

```
            EKRecurrenceFrequency frequency;
            int anzahl;

            unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
            NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
            NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
            NSDateComponents *compsMax = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:now];
            [compsMax setYear:[compsMax year] + 100];
            NSDate *hundredYearsLater = [gregorian dateFromComponents:compsMax];
            NSDate *endDate = hundredYearsLater;
            EKRecurrenceEnd *end = [EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:endDate];

            if ([_wiederholungCode isEqualToString:@"taeglich"]) {
                frequency = EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily;
                anzahl = 1;
            } else if ([_wiederholungCode isEqualToString:@"monatlich"]) {
                frequency = EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly;
                anzahl = 1;
            } else if ([_wiederholungCode isEqualToString:@"vierteljaerlich"]) {
               frequency = EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly;
               anzahl = 3;
            } else if ([_wiederholungCode isEqualToString:@"halbjaerlich"]) {
                frequency = EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly;
                anzahl = 6;
            } else if ([_wiederholungCode isEqualToString:@"jaerlich"]) {
                frequency = EKRecurrenceFrequencyYearly;
                anzahl = 1;
            } else {
                frequency = EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly;
                anzahl = 1;
            }
            EKRecurrenceRule *rule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency:frequency interval:anzahl end:end];
           [reminder addRecurrenceRule:rule];
           NSLog(@"reminder.recurrenceRules: %@", reminder.recurrenceRules);
```

In the log, directly after adding the rule:`reminder.recurrenceRules: (
    "EKRecurrenceRule <0x156b9bb0> RRULE FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=21140321T230000Z"`, so it seems the rule is correctly created, however, it is not added to the rules array.

Can anybody help me?

Note: the reminder itself and its alarm is added correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that recurrence rules only work if a date is supplied, too. So I added start date and due date to my reminders and then it works (I did not test if only supplying a start date OR a due date will work)